# Launching jobs in a for loop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am confronted with a weird problem. I have a mapreduce class which looks for patterns in a file (the patternfile goes into DistributedCache). Now I wanted to reuse this class to run for 1000 pattern files. I just had to extend the pattern matching class and override its main and run function. In the run of the child class I modify the commandline arguments and feed them to the parents run() function. Everything goes well up until iteration 45-50. Suddenly all tasktrackers start to fail until no progress is made. I checked the HDFS but still 70% of space left. Anybody any ideas as to why launching 50 jobs, one by one causes difficulties to hadoop?

```
@Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //-patterns patternsDIR input/ output/

        List<String> files = getFiles(args[1]);
        String inputDataset=args[2];
        String outputDir=args[3];



        for (int i=0; i<files.size(); i++){


            String [] newArgs= new String[4];
            newArgs = modifyArgs(args);
            super.run(newArgs);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

EDIT: Just checked the job logs, this is the first error occurring:

```
2013-11-12 09:03:01,665 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:java.io.IOException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013-11-12 09:03:32,971 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Task 'attempt_201311120807_0053_m_000053_0' has completed task_201311120807_0053_m_000053 successfully.
2013-11-12 09:07:51,717 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:java.io.IOException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013-11-12 09:08:05,973 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Task 'attempt_201311120807_0053_m_000128_0' has completed task_201311120807_0053_m_000128 successfully.
2013-11-12 09:08:16,571 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Task 'attempt_201311120807_0053_m_000130_0' has completed task_201311120807_0053_m_000130 successfully.
2013-11-12 09:08:16,571 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer: Failed to renew lease for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1595161181_30] for 30 seconds.  Will retry shortly ...
2013-11-12 09:08:27,175 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Task 'attempt_201311120807_0053_m_000138_0' has completed task_201311120807_0053_m_000138 successfully.
2013-11-12 09:08:25,241 ERROR org.mortbay.log: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013-11-12 09:08:25,241 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 54311, call heartbeat(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTrackerStatus@7fcb9c0a, false, false, true, 9834) from 10.1.1.13:55028: error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.io.IOException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:62)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.escapeString(StringUtils.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters.escape(Counters.java:768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters.access$000(Counters.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters$Counter.makeEscapedCompactString(Counters.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters$Group.makeEscapedCompactString(Counters.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters.makeEscapedCompactString(Counters.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobHistory$MapAttempt.logFinished(JobHistory.java:2276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.completedTask(JobInProgress.java:2636)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.updateTaskStatus(JobInProgress.java:1222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.updateTaskStatuses(JobTracker.java:4471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.processHeartbeat(JobTracker.java:3306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.heartbeat(JobTracker.java:3001)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)
2013-11-12 09:08:16,571 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 54311, call heartbeat(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTrackerStatus@3269c671, false, false, true, 9841) from 10.1.1.23:42125: error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.io.IOException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$Packet.<init>(DFSClient.java:2875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.writeChunk(DFSClient.java:3806)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.writeChecksumChunk(FSOutputSummer.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write1(FSOutputSummer.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:49)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:220)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:290)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:294)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:140)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:253)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.flush(PrintWriter.java:293)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.checkError(PrintWriter.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobHistory.log(JobHistory.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobHistory$MapAttempt.logStarted(JobHistory.java:2225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.completedTask(JobInProgress.java:2632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.updateTaskStatus(JobInProgress.java:1222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.updateTaskStatuses(JobTracker.java:4471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.processHeartbeat(JobTracker.java:3306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.heartbeat(JobTracker.java:3001)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

And after that we see a bunch of:

```
2013-11-12 09:13:48,204 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress: Error from attempt_201311120807_0053_m_000033_0: Lost task tracker: tracker_n144-06b.wall1.ilabt.iminds.be:localhost/127.0.0.1:47567
```

EDIT2: Some ideas?

1. The heap space error is kind of unexpected since the mappers hardly require any memory.
2. I am calling the base class with super.run(), should I use a Toolrunner call for that?
3. In every iteration a file with approximately 1000 words + score is added to the DistributedCache, I am not sure whether I should reset the cache somewhere? (every job in the super.run() runs with job.waitForCompletion(), is the cache cleared then?)

EDIT3:

@Donald: I haven't resized the memory for the hadoop daemons, so they should have a heap of 1GB each. The maptasks have 800 MB of heap from which 450 MB is used for io.sort.

@Chris: I haven't modified anything on the counters, I am using the regular ones. There are 1764 map tasks with 16 counters each, and the job itself will have another 20 or so. This might indeed add up after 50 consecutive jobs, but I would think it is not stored in the heap if you are running multiple consecutive jobs?

@Extra information:

1. The map **tasks are extremely fast**, it only takes 3-5 seconds per task, and I have jvm.reuse=-1. A map tasks processes a file with 10 records (the file is much smaller than the block size). Due to the small files I could consider making input files with 100 records to reduce the mapping overhead.
2. The first thing I tried was to add a unit reducer (**1 reduce task**) to reduce the number of files create in the HDFS, (otherwise there would be 1 per pattern and therefore 1000 per job which might create overhead for the datanodes)
3. The **number of records per job is rather low**, I am looking for specific words in 1764 files and the number of matches with one of 1000 patterns is around 5000 map output records in total)

@All: **Thanks for helping me out guys!**

Comment: can you dig up the jobtracker logs to see why they are failing?

Comment: I saw your edit. This is really strange and probably doesn't have to do with your jobs. The TaskTrackers are failing, while if the job was using too much memory the TT would stay live but the job would fail.

Comment: Have you tried upping the jvm memory limits on your task tracker vms?

Comment: Are you storing information in Counters? If so how many counters could potentially be created as part of your job? How much memory does the JT and TT's have assigned to them?

Comment: I editted the question containing the answers to your questions..

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: It's been a long time ago. I remember switching back to Amazon EMR. With my current experience I would be tempted to rewrite the problem in a higher level framework like Pig in for which it would hardly require any code. You would just have to do a join between the set of patterns and your dataset and use a UDF to look for (pattern,dataset) matches, which is actually the same function you would put in your mapper.

Comment: I think I solved it by simple launching them in  batches of 25, so no clean solution, but it worked.